# RQT graph line colour

Tags: ros, graph, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there.
Im running the rqt graph code.as you know there is lot of line, and when you move the mouse at the line, there will be colour on the line like red, green, orange,blue and others.
So what are the meaning for each colour on the rqt graph?
regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199438/rqt-graph-line-colour/) by [ghost](https://answers.ros.org/users/21020/ghost/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Each line represents a single field (from a topic) which is plotted over time.

The color of the line indicates which value it represents; the **legend** on the graph tells you which field in the topic is represented by each color.

If you're still having trouble, maybe you can edit you question to include a screenshot, and I can explain by example.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0